# Struggling to align a new DIV left, under an old DIV in CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm working on the development site for my social enterprise.

I've hooked in another div into the WooCommerce shop page (see here: http://dev2.benefacto.org/product/acton-homeless-concern/) which for the moment says 'hello, hello, hello'.

But I want it to appear under the gallery images, not above the pink summary box.

However, whatever I try in CSS (float: left, position: relative, clear: left etc) this doesn't seem to work. Frustratingly, I think it might be something to do with the 'product-gallery images' class as when you scale to a small view port the text arrives in the right place.

Cheers,

Linz

Comment: How about include this div **inside** `.product-gallery.images` ?

Comment: That's a good idea Vincent! However, I'm using a function and a WooCommerce 'Hook' to put that Div in the template, rather than editing the template itself.

I'm not sure there is a hook within the gallery I can use.

Comment: Maybe a dirty trick could be to append the div with a little javascript script ?